# Solve for all possible values of $x$: $(2+\sqrt{2})^{x^2-1} + (2-\sqrt{2})^{x^2-1} = 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for all possible values of $x$: $(2+\sqrt{2})^{x^2-1} + (2-\sqrt{2})^{x^2-1} = 4$

**My approach :**

Given, $(2+\sqrt{2})^{x^2-1} + (2-\sqrt{2})^{x^2-1} = 4$

Let $(x^2-1) = y$ and $(2+\sqrt{2}) = a$ .
Then, $(2-\sqrt{2}) = \frac{2}{a}$ .

So the equation becomes $$a^y+(\frac{2}{a})^y = 4\tag{1}$$

Now applying A.M.-G.M.,

$a^y+(\frac{2}{a})^y ≥ 2\sqrt{2^y}$

$4 ≥ 2^{\frac{y}{2}+1}$ [from $(1)$]

$2 ≥ \frac{y}{2}+1$

$1 ≥ \frac{y}{2}$

$2 ≥ y$

$2 ≥ x^2-1$

$3 ≥ x^2$

$x^2 - 3 ≤ 0$

$x \in [-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}]$

But how to proceed from here?

Although clearly $x = ±\sqrt 2$ is one of the possible solution but is there other solutions possible too?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391)

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for pointing it out . My bad actually i was just in hurry to post it without proper framing it .

Comment: This equation has no real solutions.

Comment: It does have at least two real solutions if you just test $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$. The tricky part is showing that these are the only solutions!

Comment: @GaryLiang yeah exactly that was my motive too but i failed and that's why i asked here to get delighted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(y) = (2+\sqrt{2})^{y} + (2-\sqrt{2})^{y} - 4$. Since the range of $x^2 - 1$ is $[-1,\infty)$, we are looking for solutions to $f(y) = 0$ for $y \ge -1$. I claim that the only solution is $y=1$ which corresponds to $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$.

Plotting the function helps us figure out how we might prove it.

[image: Graph of f(y)]

One way (probably not the most elegant way) to show this is to use calculus, so $$f'(y) = \log(2+\sqrt{2}) (2+\sqrt{2})^{y} + \log(2-\sqrt{2}) (2-\sqrt{2})^{y},$$
and finding the stationary points, you only have one at $$y_0 = \log\left( 1 - \frac{\log{2}}{\log(2+\sqrt{2})} \right)/\log(3+ 2\sqrt{2}) \approx -0.47154.$$

It then turns out that $f'(y) <0$ when $y <y_0$ and $f'(y) >0$ when $y > y_0$ (you can show this using the first or second derivative test). In other words, $f(y)$ is increasing when $y>y_0$, so that $y=1$ is the only root in $[y_0,\infty)$. Since $f(-1) = -2$ and $f(y)$ is decreasing $[-1,y_0]$, there are no roots in $[-1,y_0]$.